# Cache-Control: max-age=0 with stale-while-revalidate value?

Tags: http-caching

what happens if the `max-age` is zero but `stale-while-revalidate` has a value?

example: `Cache-Control: max-age=0, stale-while-revalidate=60`

will the `stale-while-revalidate` be taken into consideration at all? or the origin will be hit every time for the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A request would be sent to the origin every time.

`stale-while-revalidate` allows the client to use a stale response--while it revalidates with origin--if the response's age is less than `max-age` + `stale-while-revalidate`.

---

Here's a scenario using `Cache-Control: max-age=0, stale-while-revalidate=60`:

*A user lands on a page and then refreshes the page.*

The response is immediately stale because `max-age=0` but its `age` is within the still-usable window of time (i.e `max-age + stale-while-revalidate`).

The client loads the stale response and sends a request to the origin to revalidate it.

Comment: so which cache-control can achieve this  (for first visit no cache and sent to origin to validate, any visit after return the cached without send to origin

Comment: @MahmoudMagdy, `Cache-Control: max-age=2628000` will cache something for about a month.